# Form contents are printed outside of the form while using PHP tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have created a table for category which fetches category data from database. The table have a column having icon. upon clicking that icon , a form pops up to edit name of that particular category.i used `display:none` for form id , but only form is being hidden. contents inside form(input,button,etc) are being displayed and when i click icon a complete blank form pops up because contents are already displayed outside of the form before clicking icon.

here's the part of the code:

**HTML**

```
   <div class="category-table">
            <table border="1px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Category ID</th>
                        <th>Category Name</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>     
          
          <?php
            require("../PHP/connection.php");
               $select="SELECT *from category_details"; 
               $result=mysqli_query($con,$select);
               $num_rows= mysqli_num_rows($result);
               
               if($result){
                   if($num_rows>0){
                       while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){ 
                          
                          $id = $row["category_id"];
                          $catname = $row["category_name"];
                       echo "
                       <input type='checkbox' id='changecatcb' onclick='changecatfun()'>
                       <div class='changecat'>
                           <form id='changecatform' action='../HTML/AdminPanelChange.php' method='POST'>
                        <label for='changecatcb'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></label>
                              <p>Enter new name:</p>    
                              <input type='text' value=".$catname.">
                          <button type='submit' name='changecatbutton'>Save Changes</button>
                         </form>
                   </div>   
            
                       </div>                                   
                             <tr>
                               <td>".$id."</td>
                               <td>".$catname."</td>
                               <td>
                                    <label for='changecatcb'>
                                    <i class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true' style='color:green'></i>
                                    </label>
                               </td>     
                             </tr>
                            ";
                        }     
                                             
                   }
                   else
                   echo "<p> No Categories in Database </p>";
                   }
               }
                else
                echo "<p> Can not run query </p>";           
            ?>
             </table>      
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
       function changecatfun(){
            var form = document.getElementById('changecatform');
            var checkbox = document.getElementById('changecatcb');
              if(checkbox.checked == true){
                   form.style.display='block';
              }
              else{
                  form.style.display='none';
              }
       }
```

**CSS**

```
         .changecat form{
            position: absolute;
            background-color: white;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #555;
            height: 5%;
            width: 50%;
            left: 25%;
            display: none;
```

}

but contents are being printed inside form exactly like i want if i put the same code outside PHP tag like this:

**works outside PHP tag**

```
          <input type='checkbox' id='changecatcb' onclick='changecatfun()'>
          <div class='changecat'>
                <form id='changecatform' action='../HTML/AdminPanelChange.php' method='POST'>
                    <label for='changecatcb'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></label>
                    <p>Enter new name:</p>    
                    <input type='text' value='.$catname.'>
                    <button type='submit' name='changecatbutton'>Save Changes</button>
              </form>
           </div>
```

and yes, when i use PHP tag and inspect code in browser the form tag ends before form-contents like this:

```
          <div class="changecat">
              <form id="changecatform" action="../HTML/AdminPanelChange.php"method="POST" style="display: block;"></form>
              <label for="changecatcb"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
              <p>Enter new name:</p>
              <input type="text" value="Clothing">
              <button type="submit" name="changecatbutton">Save Changes</button>
           </div>
```

I am a beginner and this is the first time i am asking question in here. any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP.

You are trying to make `input` and `div` elements children of a `table` element, which is not allowed.

Using [a markup validator](https://validator.nu/) would have highlighted this error.

If you want those element inside a table then they must be inside a `td` or `th` element that is, in turn, inside a `tr` element.